# A class does not contain a definition for its properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i am trying to create an asp.net application using empty website.
i have created an App_code folder inside that one Utils folder and created one "CommonConstants.cs" file inside it, declared some properties and want to access those properties in Login.aspx file as shown below but it is showing 'Common.Constants does not contain a definition for 'ÄPPLICATION_TITLE' And also the properties inside CommonConstants.cs showing error "The Type or namespace name 'APPLICATION_TITLE' couldn't be found". any idea would be appreciated.

CommonConstants.cs

```
public class CommonConstants
{
    public const APPLICATION_TITLE = "Description of Project";
    public const FOOTER_YEAR = "2016";
    public const APPLICATION_DESC = "Short Desc";
    public const LOGIN_TITLE = "Login";

}
```

Login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />Utils
    <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
    <title><%CommonConstants.APPLICATION_TITLE%></title>
```

Comment: Your property declaration is wrong. You need to specify type for each property. `public const string APPLICATION_TITLE = "Description of Project";`

Comment: `CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs"` then what is this `CommonConstants` where it is defined?

Comment: @RubenVardanyan thanks its work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the class is not marked as **static** you need to first create instance of this class and then call its property like

```
CommonConstants commonconstant = new CommonConstants();
```

then call its property like this

```
commonconstant.APPLICATION_TITLE;
```

you can also do this step in your code behind to access the class

```
protected CommonConstants _commonconstant;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _commonconstant = new CommonConstants();
}
```

then in **aspx**

```
_commonconstant.APPLICATION_TITLE
```

Read about **static** class [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/static)

Comment: There is no need to mark class as static. You can access `const` properties without creating new instance.

Comment: @RubenVardanyan I tried but cannot access constant property of class directly. Can you please show

Comment: have a look at the example above